# Ghostscript causes a compilation error under LaTeX

Tags: latex, ghostscript, macos-big-sur

I recently had a big problem with a document that uses pstrick code to figure inside a document. While the document compiled perfectly, an update that I didn't pay attention to, gives me the following error for each figure:

```
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 69
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: / invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro) (r)
Execution stack:
   % interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- run --nostringval-- 2% stopped_push --nostringval-- run run false 1% stopped_push 1974 1 3% oparray_pop 1973 1 3% oparray_pop 1961 1 3% oparray_pop 1817 1 3% oparray_pop - -nostringval--% errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- run --nostringval-- 2% stopped_push --nostringval-- 1974 1 3% oparray_pop run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict: 756/1123 (ro) (G) - --dict: 0/20 (G) - --dict: 75/200 (L) -
```

and the pdf produced only includes the text present in the figures not the figures (curves, axes ...)

I am using texlive 2021 under macOS 11.3.1, mac-mini M1, texshop, xelatex

On an old iMac from 2010 running macOS 10.13.6, with texive 2018 texshop and xelatex, I do not encounter the problem

Comment: maybe related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250323

Comment: Can you check your dvipdfmx.cfg?

Comment: I just looked at the link and tried the change but still got the same error

Comment: can you show your .log file

Comment: Here are test.tex and test.log: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fa09fca8df06e7a4c347e1bbd21c585420210512221406/91f741a2c9ea857155289359cda44d7220210512221420/66812a)

Comment: The  command   xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" file        works! Thank you all for your help !

Comment: You will likely find better help asking on the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).